# Why can't operators be overloaded inside a static class?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, language-design

I have an extension class for System.Net.IPAddress and I was wanting to overload the binary operators `>, <, ==` but the compiler is telling me that I can't overload those operators inside a static class, which I must have for my other extension methods.  Is there a particular reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: We considered adding "extension operators" to C# 4, but they didn't fit into the budget and were cut. Hopefully we'll get them into a hypothetical future version of the language.

Comment: @Eric:  I would hope you get them into a "real" future version! :)  I've heard of functional programming, but not hypothetical programming!  Is that a new paradigm?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: Yes, for now it's better known as "quantum programming."

Comment: @Chris: we have not announced that there will be any changes to C# beyond C# 4. It would be premature of me to discuss possible features of a product we haven't announced and might not happen. Therefore any discussion of possible feature futures of a hypothetical next version of C# should be considered to be counterfactual musings for entertainment purposes only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Operators must relate to instances of the type in which they are declared. Since you can't have instances of a static class, it makes no sense to define operators.

There are no "extension operators" in .NET.

For your purposes, consider implementing an `IComparer<T>` (covers `<` and `>`) and / or `IEqualityComparer<T>` (covers `==`, or you *might* just use compare returning `0`; it depends whether you consider "sorts equal" and "equal" as the same).

Comment: You even got Jon Skeet removing his answer

Comment: @Jan - well, mine was 50 seconds earlier too ;-p